# How to create a Modal Popup with different url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to think how to create a Modal Popup Window that loads an HTML page and also with different URL for each popup.

[This is an example](http://www.filmtv.it/post/32262/i-film-che-hanno-formato-il-mio-immaginario/#rfr:home)

You can see that it is like a modal window with its own URL. Do you have any ideas? I have to create exactly the same thing as the example.

I tried with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var style = "top=center, left=center, width=500, height=500, status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resize=no";

    function Popup(url) {
        window.open(url, "", style);
    }
</script>
```

But I don't know how to get out about the URL thing.

Sorry for english ;)

Comment: Where are you calling `Popup()` and passing in a URL?

Comment: That's just a view styled to look like a popup. The "close" button is just a link to the homepage ("/").

Comment: @Marc I call `Popup()` in the href. `<a href="javascript:Popup('myurl')">Apri</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be referring to is `showModalDialog()` function. `Open()` would just open the url in a new tab or window.

```
var style = "top=center, left=center, width=500, height=500, status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resize=no";
function Popup(url) {
        window.showModalDialog(url, "", style )
    }
```

It's a very old approach. In order to get the modal layout closer to what you want, you can either use `bootstrap modal popup` http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp or `jquery modal popup` https://jqueryui.com/dialog/.